# pgadmin4 on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

Привет всем. У меня проблемы с установкой pgadmin4 на ubuntu 16.04.
Следую инструкции:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6_aDUMVsug&t=2s

Проделав это:
"wget https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/pip/pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl"

"pip install pgadmin4-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl"

не нашлась папка pgadmin4:

cd /lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4

Кто знает в чем проблема и как это решить?
Спасибо

Comment: У postgresql есть штатные репозитории, включая пакеты pgadmin4 для ubuntu 16.04: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

Тоже делал по этой инструкции, мне помогла смена прав на папку окружения, куда устанавливается pgadmin4 команда chmod 777. (не знаю на сколько это верно с точки зрения безопасности, я тоже новичок)